# ADS Gives Negative Input Impedance in Transmission Line Simulation

Tags: transmission-line, ads

I am trying to get a very simple transmission line input impedance simulation right in ADS, but the result gives a negative real part of the impedance. This should be impossible. Any advice on how to fix this. Here are some screenshots.
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're supposed to just plot S11 on the Smith chart,  not convert it to impedance and then plot it.

Comment: Is there a deeper reason for that or is this an ADS idiosyncrasy?

Comment: The zin function converts the s11 vector to input impedance network. Use a regular rectangular graph or a table to plot/display the value.

Comment: @Saunders, because S11 is the result you get from the simulation, being able to just plot S11 saves you having to write the equation. Also, that's fundamentally what a Smith chart does: Allows you to plot \$\Gamma\$ in polar coordinates and read off Z  from the background lines.

Answer (score 1):

The Smith chart plot should have `S[1,1]` as the plotted variable, not `Zin`.

For many scenarios this would save you having to write the equation to convert from the reflection coefficient to impedance.